# Recreating the Calendar "Day" View on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I'm looking to show a Calendar in my application, just like the iPhone Calendar application "Day" View.

The iPhone application has what looks like a Navigation Bar on the top (but doesn't perform Navigation). It has a + button to add a calendar event and possibly a left button to bring up the available calendars (if you have multiple calendars specified).

Beneath that you have The Date along with two arrows to adjust the date.

Then you have the meat of the schedule (going to use UITableView for mine).

Then you have a real button bar showing "Today" and then having the List|Day|Moth selection along with the Invitation button.

My question is how are each of these things implemented.  Specifically the top toolbar, the navigation component, and the bottom toolbar..

I'm thinking that the top 2 are just UIViews with Custom Buttons on them and the bottom is a simple UIToolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top it's probably a toolbar. Look at the XCode template for a Utility Application see how you can use this in a view using a combination of Interface Builder and code, but not have it in the context of a Navigation Stack.

Navigation component (I'm assuming you mean left/right arrows) are probably buttons that don't animate.

Comment: So you think nav item is just uiview?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've been interested as well how to rebuild the calendar's day view, and finally I found a project that shows exactly what you are searching for.

[calendar's day view](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this open-source project: [iPhone Calendar](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

Probably you would have to customize certain classes, especially the Table View for the events.

Comment: Sorry, but this recreates the "Month" view. I'm looking to recreate the "Day" view.

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked the "Day". But you can use some elements of that project, for example the arrows with the date etc.
For the test I probably would use quartz 2d to draw the day's grid and the colored events. Just have a try!

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone Calendar project, suggested by other answers looks like it'll do what you need, but just for variety, you might want to also consider the Tapku library, which contains calendar components too, specifically the month view and day view.

http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary